# Word-wrap: break-word does not work with a very long word combined with width: 100%

Tags: html, css

Why is it in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0h1wbju0/ my word-wrap: break word and width: 100% aren't being respected and the long word is not being broken up into multiple lines to fit inside it's parent div? Thanks!.

HTML:

```
    <div class="first_div">
        <fieldset class="fieldset_description"><label>Description</label>
            <div data-id="description"> fdsjalllffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.first_div {
  width: 200px;
}

.fieldset_description {
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.description {
  max-width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: `word-break: break-word`

Comment: @CBroe Do you mean `word-break: break-all`?

Comment: You're correct, I implemented the fix outlined in the linked issue and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have to mention to @CBroe and @Bryan that `word-break: break-word` will work on Chrome, but not on Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

you should use =>

```
`word-break: break-all;`
```

[Working code jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8uw46dmm/)